# Optimization of matrix with each sum of a column is equal to 1

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I have a matrix where the values in each column need to be optimised such that the error with a following equation is minimised.

Each number in the matrix must be decimal and equal to or between zero and one.
The columns summed up need, to sum up to 1. So each number represents a proportion of something.

For this, I'm using `scipy.optimize.minimize()` with bounds for all the values such that they fit the restraints. The matrix is flattened to be usable in the optimize function.

The resulting optimised matrix fits the restraints but fails to archive the necessary constraint of reaching 1 when a column is summed up.

What can I do to make sure that each column reaches one with this function or do you have a suggestion for a better optimizer?

**Finished Minimisation:**

[image]

**Optimized Matrix:**

[image]

**Summed up columns (Should be 1. for every entry):**

[image]

Comment: If you write down the mathematical model, it becomes clearer what type of solver to use.

Comment: Please provide your code, otherwise it is hard to help.